# Is $\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{15}}$ irrational?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

In general I was wondering if $\cos\theta$ was between $0$ and $1$ exclusive then would $\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{15}}$ be irrational? And just on another note is an irrational times a transcendental a transcendental?

Thank you for taking the time to read this question and answering this question.

Comment: Can you split this into 2 questions? I can answer 1 at a time.

Comment: There certainly exists $\theta$ such that $\cos\theta=1/\sqrt{15}$, and in this case $(\cos\theta)/\sqrt{15}=1/15$ is rational. For the second question: $e^{-1}$ is transcendental, but $e^{-1}e=1$ is rational.

Comment: Does your second question mean "algebraic times transcendental=transcendental"?  Excluding cases like $0\times e= 0$  that one is correct.

Comment: Thank you I understand now. Thanks for the help!